# Unite Collection of Collections into Collection in a method in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I've created a Collection class that extends ArrayList to add some useful methods. It looks like this:

```
public class Collection<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    //some methods...
}
```

I want to be able to unite a Collection of Collections to a single Collection, like this:

```
{{1, 2}, {2,3}, {1}, {2}, {}} -> {1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2}
```

I have an idea of how a static method should look like:

```
public static<E> Collection<E> unite(Collection<Collection<E>> arr) {
    Collection<E> newCollection = new Collection<>();

    for(Collection<E> element : arr) {
        newCollection.merge(element);
    }

    return newCollection;
}
```

But I don't know how to make this method non-static(so that it accepts no arguments, like this:

```
Collection<E> list = listOfLists.unite();
```

). Is that even possible? If it is, can you please help me with it?

Comment: The name `Collection` is already used by the Java collections framework (for the general interface of all collections). Reintroducing a class with that name will confuse every reader and that leads to bugs. I suggest to pick a different name.

Comment: Note that you can use `flatMap` of the stream-api for that. `lists.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: I want to be able to do it in a method, so that a chain would be nice-looking

Comment: Could be done in kotlin, with extension methods, but I think there is no real "java" way to do that

Comment: How do you think the call should look like? How should the method know both lists when you do not use arguments? It can only know the current list if it is not static, but not a second list. `list.unite(other)` would be possible. And again, my stream-example shows how to implement such a method. Just pack all your lists into `lists`. `return List.of(firstList, secondList).stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to do it for any concrete type `T`. If `T` is not of a `Collection` type, then `unite()` is an irrelevant method (if you have a `ArrayListModified<Double>`, for example, you can't flatten it because that's absurd).

So you either have to make `T` bounded to collections:

```
public class ArrayListModified<E, T extends Collection<E>> extends ArrayList<T> {

    public Collection<E> unite() {
        Collection<E> newCollection = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Collection<E> element : this) {
            newCollection.addAll(element);
        }

        return newCollection;
    }
}
```

Or use a static method that takes one `ArrayListModified<ArrayListModified<E>>` parameter just as in your current implementation (though it wouldn't be required to be static).

Answer (score 0):

A way would be to explicitly declare the type parameter to be a `List<E>` and then its pretty much straight forward:

```
class NestedList<E> extends ArrayList<List<E>> {
    public List<E> flatten() {
        return stream()
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try use '?' instead of 'E'. Idk whether im right.

```
public Collection<?> unite(Collection<Collection<?>> collection) {
        Collection<?> newCollection = new Collection<>();

        for(Collection<?> element : collection) {
            newCollection.merge(element);
        }

        return newCollection;
    }
```

Comment: I want no arguments passed: Collection<T> collection = collectionOfCollections.unite()

Comment: It is likely a better idea to not write an answer if you are not sure whether it will solve the issue or not.